# How do I get a javascript 'for' loop to iterate when and only when I want it to?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have a 'for' loop in Javascript and I want to be in full control of when the loop iterates. Here's a little code:

```
for (var j=0; j < number; j++){
    $('#question').empty;
    $('#question').append('' + operand1[j], operator[j], operand2[j] + ' = ');
    $('#answer').keyup(function() {
        if($('#answer').val() == answers[j]){
            return 'correct';
        }
    });
}
```

The `return 'correct'` is when I want it to iterate, and I don't want it iterate otherwise.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You're not really getting the concept of for loops or how to set event handlers at all !

Comment: I essentially want to loop through a series of questions, and when a user enters the correct answer for a question, I want the next question to appear

Comment: You're doing it backwards. You should use .on() for keyup on all questions, then have that callback be the test to display the next question.

Comment: Ahh yeah I'm an idiot, I dunno why I was stuck on the idea of using a loop for this lol 
thanks for the help

Comment: BTW, instead of lots of different arrays `operator`, `operand1`, `operand2`, `answers`, better practice is an array of objects: `var questions = [{operand1: 1, operator: '+', operand2: 2, answer: 3}, ...];`. This keeps all the related pieces together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a function...

```
$('#answer').keyup(function() {
    var val = $('#answer').val(), answerIndex;
    // if the value is equal to one of the answers
    if ((answerIndex = answers.indexOf(val)) > -1) {
       correct(answerIndex); // call the `correct` function.
    }
});

function correct(answerIndex) {
   $('#question').empty;
   $('#question').append('' + operand1[answerIndex], operator[answerIndex], operand2[answerIndex] + ' = ');
}
```